# EF Core - Exclude from IQueryable if Datetime-Value is between 2 DateTimes from a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

I'm currently trying to achieve the following :

I have an IQueryable (UserDataDateRange) that has "from" and "to" DateTime-Values and another bigger IQueryable (UserData) with a DateTime-value and basically I want to exclude every data from userdata that Datetime-value is between the "from" and "to" comparing it to every UserDataDateRange-Entry.
Also every DateTime is nullable and I just want to ignore those.

Here is what I have tried :

```
private IQueryable<Userdata> ExcludeIfInDaterange(IQueryable<Userdata> query)
{
    var dateRangeQuery = DBContext.UserDateDateRange.Where(x => x.From.HasValue && x.To.HasValue);
    query = query.Where(l => !l.UserDate.HasValue);
    foreach (var q in dateRangeQuery)
    {     
        query = query.Where(l => l.UserDate.Value <= q.From.Value && l.UserDate.Value >= q.To.Value);
    }
    return query;
}
```

From my understanding this should work? Also I have tried avoid using something like "toArray" because from my understanding an IQueryable is basically the SQL that im manipulating and something toArray gives me the actual data.
However I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, theres no real exception, im just getting the following error :

> Could not get function from a frame. The code is not available. The
> error code is CORDBG_E_CODE_NOT_AVAILABLE, or0x80131309.

My function seems to break the query but i cant figure out why. I cant even use "Count()", it gives me the same error.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
l.UserDate.Value <= q.From.Value && l.UserDate.Value >= q.To.Value
```

How can a date be both earlier than the `From` date **and** later than the `To` date at the same time? Unless you have some very odd data in your `UserDateDateRange` table, that filter will exclude all records.

You're also combining two mutually-exclusive filters with an `AND` operator, which is another way to exclude all records:

- `!l.UserDate.HasValue` : `UserDate` is `NULL`
- `l.UserDate.Value <= ...` : Can't possibly be satisfied, since `UserDate` is `NULL`

And there's no need to use `.Value` when comparing nullable properties with `<` / `<=` / `>` / `>=`.

Try something like:

```
private IQueryable<Userdata> ExcludeIfInDaterange(IQueryable<Userdata> query)
{
    var dateRangeQuery = DBContext.UserDateDateRange.Where(x => x.From.HasValue && x.To.HasValue);
    return query.Where(l => !l.UserDate.HasValue || !dateRangeQuery.Any(q => q.From <= l.UserDate && l.UserDate <= q.To));
}
```